# One way transition delay

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a sidebar with a logo on the top. Next to the sidebar is a button, which is used to switch between the normal and compact class of the sidebar. This changes the width of the sidebar, so I added a `0.25s transition-duration`, so it has a nice opening and closing animation. The buttonpress also changes the source of the logo. What I want to do is when I first click on the button (in normal view) it changes the image instantly, but when I click on it a second time (in compact view) the image has a `0.25s transition-delay` so it only changes after the sidebar has finished opening. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

```css
sidebar {
  background: red;
  transition: background 1s;
}

sidebar.active {
  background: pink;
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<div>click</div>
<sidebar>
  lorem ipsum
</sidebar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to using jQuery (or vanilla Javascript, for that matter)?

(psuedo code/untested)

in css:

```
.sidebar-logo.delay-transition {
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
 }
```

in script:

```
$('.my-special-button').on('click', function() {
    $('.sidebar-logo').addClass('delay-transition');
})
```

So, as soon as you click the button the first time it adds a class to give the sidebar a delay.  It will continue to behave that way for each subsequent click.